# how to use an External Value (type JSON) in SwaggerUI and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, swagger, static-files, swagger-3.0

openapi: "3.0.0"
Swagger-jsdoc: "^6.2.5",
Swagger-ui-express: "^4.3.0",
Node: v18.8.0

I have a payload with a field called raw_data who is super long. So I decided to use an external value and call it in swaggerUI

I'm using this URL: https://mywebsite/tremorData.json which its being called. It is just a JSON file. Is possible that the problems is caused by the JSON file not being parsed?

I tried several things but it never works. In case you know how to add big payload in swaggerUI I'm open to other options.

this is my code:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /data/tremor:
 *   post:
 *
 *     security:
 *     -  bearerAuth: []
 *
 *     tags: [data/ Tremor]
 *
 *     requestBody:
 *        required: true
 *        content:
 *           application/json:
 *              examples:
 *               jsonObject:
 *                 summary: A sample object
 *                 externalValue: 'https://mywebsite/tremorData.json'
 *            
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Successful operation
 *       400:
 *         description: validation Fail /or/ Unexpected token, in JSON at position 108
 */
```

the render in swaggerUI :
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "could not render" error happens because the `requestBody` does not have a `schema`. Adding a minimal schema, e.g. just `type: object` without any `properties` (which means "arbitrary object") will avoid the rendering error.

```
 *     requestBody:
 *        required: true
 *        content:
 *           application/json:
 *              schema:         # <-----
 *                type: object  # <-----
 *              examples:
...
```

As for `externalValue`, it's the correct way to reference external examples, but unfortunately it's not supported by Swagger UI yet. You can track this issue for status updates:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5433

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try that and let you know what happend :)

Comment: Hi @Helen, I add the lines and also i tried calling a schema. In both cases is not working and is loggin  the same error. 

Is possible that my URL is only a JSON file.. Should i add a parsed object ?